# Can't access web site hosted on Azure VM

Tags: azure, iis, windows-server-2019, azure-vm

I have a website hosted in IIS on an Azure Windows Server VM (Datacenter 2019). I can telnet to port 80 on the VM (and as you'd expect this stops working if I try disabling the relevant Windows Firewall rule), and I can access the site from a browser on the VM, but can't browse to the site from outside the machine. I have the following:

- A public IP address
- A network security group
- An inbound rule in the NSG: Source = any, source port range = *, destination = internal IP address of VM, service = HTTP
- As above for HTTPS, although I'm really only concerned with HTTP for now, I haven't set up a certificate yet
- The port 80 inbound rule open in Windows Firewall (hence the telnet working).

If it makes a difference, this Azure instance has two separate resource groups, one for each client. The other client has a running site accessible to the internet.

Comment: What's the IIS site binding?

Comment: IIS binding is as follows:

Type = http; Port = 80; IP address = 10.0.0.4 (the internal IP address of the VM)

Comment: Please expand on "can't browse to the site from outside the machine" - what error do you get?

Comment: If I try to access the site from Chrome on my home PC, using either the public IP address or the free DNS address that Azure gives me for the VM, I get "This site can’t be reached", which is the same as if I put in a random garbage URL into Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: The site was actually running fine. This ended up being because browsers add the www automatically, despite me trying to work around this by disabling automatic URL modifications in Firefox (there's an about:config setting for this). A colleague had the same idea, but worked around it by putting an entry in the hosts file.

Comment: Throughout your question, you don't even mention what's in the URL address bar. If you test `http://public_ip` first, you won't waste so much time.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried disabling Firefox automatically adding the www, and several other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Then inbound rule in the NSG, should like below:**

```
Source = public ip of client vm, source port range = *, destination = any, service = HTTP
```

Comment: No luck with that either I'm afraid. The "other client" I mentioned in the original comment , which works correctly, does it this way (which I'm going to set mine to after making this post): Source = any; source port range = *; destination = IP addresses; destination IP address = 10.0.0.4; Service = custom; Destination port ranges = 80,443; Protocol = Any; Action = Allow

Comment: @TonyKelly According to your last comment, it is obvious that you are accessible on the internal network, but not on the public network.

Comment: Yes and no: I can telnet into the port on the VM from the public network, which I can confirm by toggling the Windows Firewall rule on or off (on = can telnet, off = can't telnet), however I'm only able to browse the website from the same VM. I haven't tested another VM on the same virtual network, so I'm not sure what the result would be for that.